# Complex jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, selector

I have hard time figuring out the correct jQuery selector for my problem.

What I have:

1) 11 divs, that has class "theCycle", 10 of them are hidden, one displayed
2) There is inputs in the current displayed div element
3) Some inputs have class "required"

What I need:

Need to select class "theCycle", then inputs with class "required" and then check if they are filled.

So far what I have tried fails or still says that my inputs arent filled.

Comment: Can you post your code ? html and js are always helpful for providing answers that are easily tested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  $(".theCycle:visible input.required").each(function(){
    if ($(this).val() != ""){
       //it's not empty
    } 
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, this works too. But somebody posted a shorter solution but hte post got deleted. This works fine too - $('.theCycle:visible input.required');

Comment: But, this only will work for the first input. Need to add ".each"

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.theCycle:visible input.required').each(function() {
  if ($(this).val() != '') {
    ...
  }
})
```

Something like this should work :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with .filter() to get the selector with the desired elements:

```
var inputs = $("div.theCycle:visible input.required").filter(function(){
     return $(this).val() != ""
});
```